# Django no me permite enviar correos

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo electronico desde django, pero no me permite. Me da este error

raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w187sm11407776qkb.81 - gsmtp')

Lo unico que hice fue configurar mi settings.py de la siguiente manera

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxx"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="xxxx"
```

luego abri el shell e hice lo siguiente

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send mail
>>> send_mail('Asunto','Mensaje','xxxx@gamil.com',['xxxxx@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

Ya le di permiso de acceso de apps menos seguras

Answer (score 0):

En la parte de EMAIL_HOST_USER estas poniendo tu cuenta de Gmail y en EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD el password que te genero Gmail para tu app? Te sugiero que revises aquí: https://dev.to/abderrahmanemustapha/how-to-send-email-with-django-and-gmail-in-production-the-right-way-24ab

Se explica detalladamente como hacer el envió de correos con Gmail.

Como alternativa te recomiendo utilizar https://sendgrid.com/ es un servicio que te permite enviar correos de manera gratuita junto con muchas funcionalidades mas.